# How to stop showing sticky floating footer bar on specific page and posts in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress-theming

I  have added a sticky floating footer bar to my site and it works great but I want to hide or stop showing the footer bar on specific posts and pages on my site. Check live demo https://whatsapgroupslink.com/

I used some CSS and js code to implement this footer bar.

First I used this code in elements and hook to generate after footer and display rule is the entire site.

```
<div class="wplogout-footer-bar-fixed">
<div class="notice-inner grid-container">
        <div id="wplogout-footer-bar-fixed">
    <span>Get Free Access and VIP Support</span><button id="wplogout-closebar" type="button">X</button>
</div>
```

Second I use this code in elements and hook to wp footer and display rule is the entire site.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("wplogout-closebar").onclick = function() {
    var z = document.getElementById("wplogout-footer-bar-fixed");
    if (z.style.display == 'none') {
        z.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        z.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Lastly, I added following CSS

```
.wplogout-footer-bar-fixed {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: #0f0f0f;
color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
.wplogout-footer-bar-fixed span {
padding-right: 10px;
font-size: 16px;
```

}

```
#wplogout-closebar {
float: right;
padding: 5px 9px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #eee;
color: #34495e;
line-height: 1em;
```

}